# Solve for $z \in \mathbb{R}$ : $z^6 = -64$

Tags: complex-numbers

I can only think of the solutions 2i and -2i, but there should be more solutions. I am very new to complex numbers and equations and was wondering if anyone could help with the following question:

Solve for $z \in \mathbb{R}$ : $z^6 = -64$

Comment: Write $z=re^{it}$.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't it be $z\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel If not, it’s a very easy problem

Comment: If you're confident you wrote the problem out correctly, no solutions. Done. You already have an answer to accept.

Answer (score 2):

If $z\in \Bbb R$ then $z^6 \ge 0$ as it is the square of $z^3$. So no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Solve using the exponential form of $z$: if $z=r\mathrm e^{i\theta}$, the equation becomes
$$z^6=r^6\mathrm e^{6i\theta}=-64=2^6\mathrm e^{i\pi}$$
so that
\begin{cases}
r^6=2^6 \quad\text{(and }r>0),\\
6\mkern 1mu\theta\equiv \pi\mod 2\pi.
\end{cases}
Can you end the computations?

Answer (score 0):

$-64$ can be written as $-64=64(\cos\pi+i\sin\pi)$.

Set $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

$$z^6=r^6\left(\cos(6\theta)+i\sin(6\theta)\right)$$
To solve $z^6= -64$ we must solve
$$r^6\left(\cos(6\theta)+i\sin(6\theta)\right)=64(\cos\pi+i\sin\pi)$$
Which gives us $r^6=64\to r=2$ and $6\theta=\pi+2k\pi$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$

This means $\theta_k=\frac{\pi}{6}+k\frac{\pi}{3}$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$

Substitute the six values of $k$ and get the six roots of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to go through [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826117/823370) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3831171/823370).

Proceeding as the above solutions, you mentioned that you got the solution $2i$. The value of $n$ here is $6$. So, we get a hexagon as shown

[image]

As you can see that none of the complex numbers which satisfy this equation lie on the real number line, so your equation has no real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$z^6+64=0 \iff (z^3)^2-(8i)^2=0 \iff (z^3-8i)(z^3+8i)=0 \iff z^3-8i=0$ or $z^3+8i=0$

For example $z^3-8i=0 \iff \Big( \frac{z}{-2i} \Big) ^3=1 \iff w^3=1$ with $w= \frac{z}{-2i}$. The other case is analogous.

Can you take it from here?